# Why does dex2jar create 50 identical errors

Tags: apk, decompiler, dex2jar

i run dex2jar but after finished it says there were 50 errors.
All 50 error-files are the same and have in line two of the error-file:
"java.lang.RuntimeException: can not merge I and Z".
After this follows the position where  the error occured.

The created jar-file (~10MB) can be opened in JD-GUI but has perhaps more content if there is no error when creating it.

How can i get rid of there errors?

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried Enjarify? https://github.com/Storyyeller/enjarify

Comment: Thx for the tip. I tried to use it but it generartes a 0 byte output jar-file :-(

Output-screenshot --> https://ibb.co/4dgRsjJ

Comment: Enjarify requires Python 3. You were running it using Python 2.

Comment: Ah, ok i used "pypy2.7-v7.3.0-win32".

Comment: Did it work when you ran it with Python 3?